# Is it possible to write a generic function to extract objects within a object which are generified?

Tags: java, generics

I have a simple data structure

```
class Triple<S,V,O>{
 private S s;
 private V v;
 private O o;

 ... //constructor

 private Object getParameter(int index){
  switch(index){
  case 0: return s;
  case 1: return v;
  case 2: return o;
 }
}
```

I then have a set of triples `Set<Triple> tripleSet;`

I have a function to create a set of elements at a particular index from a set of triples.

```
public Set<Object> extractColumn(Set<Triple> tripleSet, int index){
 Set<Object> columnElements = new HashSet<Object>();
 for(Triple t : tripleSet){
   columnElements.add(t.get(index);
 }
 return columnElements;
}
```

Now whenever I extract a column it is a set of objects and when using the objects in the returned set, I have to cast it to the corresponding type. Is there a generic-way to code this datastructure and the function to extract the elements?

Comment: Don't use a single getter. Use a getter per field. If you're going to return different types, the only acceptable type that covers all of them is `Object`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Does that mean that I also need to use different functions instead of a single `extractColumn`?

Comment: Yes, I feel like you want to do something that might be better achieved with Reflection.

Comment: You could make all 3 objects extend the same class or interface but it is doubtful how much useful that would be. I agree with @SotiriosDelimanolis here. Perhaps if you added some code for what data this `Triple` holds and how they are used then maybe a better idea comes up

Comment: The normal model for getters is to have one per field: e.g., `getLength(); getWidth();`, and so on. Why not `getS(); getV(); getO();`, just as @SotiriosDelimanolis suggests?

Answer (score 2):

How about parameterizing each of your extract methods? For example:

```
public <TypeS> Set<TypeS> extractColumnS(Set<? extends Triple<TypeS, ?, ?>> tripleSet) {
  Set<TypeS> columnElements = new HashSet<TypeS>();
  for (Triple<TypeS, ?, ?> t : tripleSet) {
    columnElements.add(t.getS());
  }
  return columnElements;
}
```

This is following up on one of the comments to create getters for each element of your triple.

Comment: You'll want it to take `Set<? extends Triple<TypeS, ?, ?>>` - nested wildcards don't capture.

Comment: @PaulBellora Thanks for catching that.